# List all files associated with a tag on CVS command line

Tags: cvs

Is there a way on the CVS command line to list all files associated with a tag?

Comment: I'm still amazed that people still use CVS.  :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find out which CVS tags cover which files and paths?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817/how-to-find-out-which-cvs-tags-cover-which-files-and-paths)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

About the closest you'll be able to get is with this:

cvs -q log -R -N -S -rTAGNAME

This works against local copy, it doesn't pull from the server.

EDIT:

As Ken mentioned, a slight variation will make it pull from the server, but in this situation you need to specify the module name too.

cvs -q rlog -R -N -S -rTAGNAME MODULENAME

Comment: That works.  And since I have many files without the tag, using the uppercase -Q option instead of -q suppressed all the noise.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: corrected command below to include Module Name (see above)

```
cvs -q rlog -R -N -S -rTAGNAME MODULENAME
```

will work against the repository, NOT the local copy

Still about as close as you'll get with CVS.

The command [Bill the Lizard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard) posted will work with CVSNT.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's

```
cvs ls -lR -r tag
```

but I'm on SVN now, so you'll have to test it.